# FTP directory listing failed

Tags: linux, ftp, vsftpd

I created a FTP user for a Linux server and used filezilla to connect with that server.

I am seeing login is success but directory listing is failed. Is there any change that I missed ?
[image]

My vsftpd.conf file contains,

```
chroot_local_user =YES
local_enable = Yes
idle_session_timeout=600
pasv_min_port=2121
pasv_max_port=2142
log_ftp_protocol=YES
syslog_enable=YES
pasv_enable=YES
```

I opened 2121 to 2142 ports in UFW.

Comment: I would open **all** port between 2121 and 2142.

Comment: Your `vsftpd.conf` is not being take into account, as the server obviously uses a different passive port range. The first connection goes to 6084, the second goes to 48621. + Post a full text log file of FileZilla, not screenshot of a part of the log.

Comment: You know you're giving away your IP address in the screenshot?  It starts with 139 and is hosted by linode.com.  BTW, the client wouldn't happen to have a firewall too?

Comment: Weclome on the Unix SE! I you can copy-paste text instead of uploading screenshot, do the first! It is important. Now as a new user it will be probably tolerated from you, but it would be still better if you would replace the screenshot with a copy-paste (if it is possible).

Answer (score 1):

You should check the logfile (in some cases /var/log/syslog or /var/log/messages if not specified). You can set it with this parameter in /etc/vsftpd.conf:

```
xferlog_file=/var/log/vsftpd.log
```

Don't forget to restart the service, try again and check the logfile for entries.

In most cases it is a permission problem in a parent directory that the user can not enter this directory. I just see "/var/www" in your post and it is possible that you missed the "x" flag for some folder permissions. If they are owned by an other user and/or group, you probably need to set it to "others".

Furthermore you should check the file /etc/shells. It should contain the users shell for logging in. This mistake is done very often that a user is added with /bin/false but the shell is not allowed in this file so you get logged out with an error.

Last but not least: Try to run the service without 'chroot_local_user=YES' to check if it is a login or permission problem.

But first of all: check your logs to find a hint. They should provide something to you.

Answer (score 1):

The passive mode connection can't be established. There is most likely an issue with the tcp traffic not being able to be sent/received over passive mode ports between your ftp client and the ftp server.

- Check local firewall on your client.
- Check firewall and port forwarding on your internet router.
- Double check UFW settings on your server. `ufw status verbose` should list a line like this: `2121:2142/tcp            ALLOW IN    Anywhere`
- Look for other issues. Maybe this one: [adding seccomp_sandbox=NO](https://askubuntu.com/questions/592577/vsftpd-pasv-configuration-set-up-yet-still-not-working).

Answer (score -1):

You have set `chroot_local_user` to `YES` and in the image, the FTP server is trying to open `/var/www/....` - is that the local users `home` directory?